# Is OWASP ESAPI .NET Edition really used? Is this project still alive?

Tags: .net, owasp, esapi

I have just seen that the last release has been pushed out in 2009 and that raised my doubts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, as you've noted, it was abandoned in 2010, and is completely unsupported and thoroughly outdated at this point in time.  You should definitely look somewhere else, and where exactly depends on your specific needs.